# how to fetch a specific B managed object from a to-many relationship from A to B, based on one of B's attributes?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

That is, I have an entity A with a to-many relationship with entity B. B instances have, among other attributes, a creationDate. And I also already have a managed object for A in memory.

So I know I can access all B instances through A's accessor. But I'd like to do something along the lines of:

"for all Bs in A.relationshipName, return the managed object for the B with the most recent B.creationData"

How could I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternately, since you already have a managed object A in memory, you could do an in-memory filtered sort of the A->>B relationship.

```
A *inMemoryA = ...

id byDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES];
id sorters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:byDate, nil];
NSArray *sortedBs = [inMemoryA allBs] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorters];

B *mostRecentB = [sortedBs lastObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

How about performing another fetch request:

Assuming the relationship name on the one of the one-to-many side is `a`

```
// 1
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity  = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"B"
                                           inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;

// 2
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

// 3
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.a = %@", previouslyFetchedAObject];

// 4
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate"
                                                               ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
```

---

In plain English

1. Make a new fetch request for B
2. Set the fetch limit so you only return 1 object
3. Set a predicate that only pulls back objects that have a relationship to the already fetched A object
4. Set the order descending on date so you get newest dates first